# C# Add Extra json Tags

Tags: c#, asp.net, json, rest

I am trying to return json data from a Web Service. I am able to return data just fine but the consumer of the web service wants the data in a certain format with additional tags.

How do I add these extra tags to a json return in a C# RESTful service?

I want to add:

```
  "getProfilesByImisidResponse": {
    "getProfilesByImisidResult": {
      "profileResponse": [
```

also add:

```
"RegisteredOwner": [
```

**Current Return:**

```
[
  {
    "AVRRProfileId": "AVRRP000000169",
    "ESBTransactionGuId": "d28cb710-9ff5-45f8-a5a6-e779aaf07151",
    "ErrorMessage": null,
    "Transaction": null,
    "RegisteredOwners": [
      {
        "FirstName": "Kevin",
        "LastName": " Dunn"
      },
      {
        "FirstName": "Elaine",
        "LastName": " Dunn"
      }
    ]
  },
  {
    "AVRRProfileId": "AVRRP000000170",
    "ESBTransactionGuId": "d28cb710-9ff5-45f8-a5a6-e779aaf07151",
    "ErrorMessage": null,
    "Transaction": null,
    "RegisteredOwners": [
      {
        "FirstName": "Kevin",
        "LastName": " Dunn"
      },
      {
        "FirstName": "Elaine",
        "LastName": " Dunn"
      }
    ]
  }
]
```

**Needed Retrun:**

```
{
  "getProfilesByImisidResponse": {
    "getProfilesByImisidResult": {
      "profileResponse": [
        {
          "AVRRProfileId": "AVRRP000000169",
          "ESBTransactionGuid": null,
          "ErrorMessages": null,
          "Transaction": null,
          "RegisteredOwners": {
            "RegisteredOwner": [
              {
                "FirstName": "Kevin",
                "LastName": " Dunn"
              },
              {
                "FirstName": "Elaine",
                "LastName": " Dunn"
              }
            ]
          }
        },
        {
          "AVRRProfileId": "AVRRP000000170",
          "ESBTransactionGuid": null,
          "ErrorMessages": null,
          "Transaction": null,
          "RegisteredOwners": {
            "RegisteredOwner": [
              {
                "FirstName": "Kevin",
                "LastName": " Dunn"
              },
              {
                "FirstName": "Elaine",
                "LastName": " Dunn"
              }
            ]
          }
        }
      ]
    }
  }
}
```

**My Code:**

**AVRRService.svc.cs:**

```
using System;
...

namespace AXWCFLINQ
{
    public class AVRRService : IAVRRService
    {
        private daoAVRR daoAVRR = new daoAVRR();

        public List<profileResponse> getProfilesByImisid(IMISIdRequest imisIdRequest)
        {
            return daoAVRR.getProfilesByImisid(imisIdRequest);
        }
    }
}
```

**IAVRRService.cs:**

```
using System;
...

namespace AXWCFLINQ
{
    // NOTE: You can use the "Rename" command on the "Refactor" menu to change the interface name "IAVRRService" in both code and config file together.
        [OperationContract]
        [WebInvoke
           (UriTemplate = "/getProfilesByImisid",
            RequestFormat = WebMessageFormat.Json,
            ResponseFormat = WebMessageFormat.Json, Method = "POST")] 
        List<profileResponse> getProfilesByImisid(IMISIdRequest imisIdRequest);
    }
}
```

**Method in daoAVRR.cs**

```
public List<profileResponse> getProfilesByImisid(IMISIdRequest imisIdRequest)
{
    List<profileResponse> AVRRList = null;
    string IMISId = "";

    IMISId = imisIdRequest.imisId;
    try
    {
        var aVRRInfo = from a in db.AMA_AVRR_PROFILEs
                       where (a.IMISID == IMISId && a.ACTIVE == 1)
                       select new profileResponse
                       {
                           AVRRProfileId = a.AVRRPROFILEID,
                           ESBTransactionGuId = a.ESBTRANSACTIONGUID,
                           ImisId = a.IMISID,
                           RegisteredOwners = GetRegisteredOwnerList(a.REGISTEREDOWNER1, a.REGISTEREDOWNER2),
                           ErrorMessage = "",
                           Transaction = GetTransactionByAVRRProfileId(a.AVRRPROFILEID)
                       };

        AVRRList = aVRRInfo.ToList();
    }
    catch (Exception e)
    {
        string ex = e.ToString();
    }
    return AVRRList;
}
```

**profileResponse.cs:**

```
public class profileResponse
{
    public string AVRRProfileId { get; set; }

    public string ESBTransactionGuId { get; set; }
    public string ErrorMessage { get; set; }
    public List<RegisteredOwner> RegisteredOwners { get; set; }
    public Transaction Transaction { get; set; }
}
```

Comment: wrap profileResponse in a new class

Comment: @Steve Thank you for the suggestion.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
public class ProfileResponse
{
    public string AVRRProfileId { get; set; }
    public string ESBTransactionGuId { get; set; }
    public string ErrorMessage { get; set; }
    public RegisteredOwners RegisteredOwners { get; set; }
    public Transaction Transaction { get; set; }
}

public class ProfileResponseWrapper 
{
    [JsonProperty(Name = "getProfilesByImisidResponse")]
    public ProfilesByImisResponse response;
}

public class ProfilesByImisResponse
{
    [JsonProperty(Name = "getProfilesByImisidResult")]
    public ProfilesByImisResult result;
}

public class ProfilesByImisResult
{
    [JsonProperty(Name = "profileResponse")]
    public List<ProfileResponse> ProfileResponses;
}

public class RegisteredOwners
{
    public List<RegisteredOwner> RegisteredOwner; //You should consider naming these differently as this isn't ideal for clarity
}
```

This should give you what you want, I've used `JsonProperty` assuming your using `Newtonsoft.Json` but you can just name the Properties with the JSON name directly if not.

Of course you need to construct and then return a `ProfileResponseWrapper` to be converted to JSON when fulfilling the request.

Comment: Thank you. I am not using Newtonsoft but I can just name the class like you suggested.

Answer (score 1):

You need to create classes for getProfilesByImisidResponse,     getProfilesByImisidResult, profileResponse and RegisteredOwners

For example:

```
public class RegisteredOwners : List<RegisteredOwner>
{
}
```

Since you already have a profileResponse class i suggest to create a profileResponses class

```
public class profileResponses : List<profileResponse>
{
}
```

Comment: Thank you for the suggestion.